# How can I check how many suggested edits are approved/rejected by me?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I am not able to find how I can see how many suggested edits are approved/rejected by me.

Right now I can only see the number of reviews done by me. Also from **"stats"** and **"history"** I can only see the list of reviews done.

However, if someone (who has rep less than 2k) has edited a question/answer and is waiting for edit approval, then they can click on the **More** tab and see the number of reviews that XYZ person has approved/rejected.

Is there any similar kind of thing to check the stat of approved/rejected suggested edits?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to [your profile -> Activity -> All actions -> Reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3126646/kampai?tab=activity&sort=reviews), open an edit you reviewed, and check your reviewer stats. :)

[image]

> Kampai has approved 37 edit suggestions and rejected 44 edit suggestions