# Add Edit Approval/Rejection Stats to Profile

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I was looking to see what my statistics were for reviewing suggested edits and could not find that info until I came across [How to check that how many suggested edit approve and reject by me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277964/how-to-check-that-how-many-suggested-edit-approve-and-reject-by-me)

The answer:

> Go to your profile -> activity -> reviews, open an edit you reviewed,
>   and check your reviewer stats.

seems a little convoluted. Couldn't this info be added to my profile on the Reviews page (right under the spot indicating the total number of reviews)?

Comment: Are the reviewer stats actually accurate now? Earlier this week they were still busted anyway.

Comment: I suppose we should also insist that the stats be accurate as well :)

Comment: Text is outdated (doesn't reflect the recent "profile changes") and stats are still wrong.

Comment: Well, yes, but it's been horrendously wrong for some considerable time.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**I like it**

I can understand your point here, it would be nice to see that easily.

**But will the other queues feel left out, sad, and depressed? :(**

But then where do you stop? Do you also add cv reviews and how many you voted to close/leave open? Same with the reopen queue.

The triage queue would be another one where it might be nice to easily see these stats.

Your suggestion of putting it under the total edits number isn't bad but may make it look a little hanky. And if people later wanted those other queue statistics then they would be all over the place.

**Give them a special place in your profile so they too can feel warm and cozy**

A possibly better place would be a "statistics" page/tab to include all of that information. This could be helpful in seeing your tendencies and if you should look closer at what you are doing and how you are handling things. This would also show how much you are doing in each queue in one place. So you may decide that you would like to spend more time in somewhere you've been neglecting (yes, I know not every queue is meant for everyone and that's ok).

Maybe next to the "Activity" tab would be the best place for something like this. It could probably do a good job of filling a whole itself and the "actions" tab below is already a little cluttered.

**Enough reading. Let's look at some talented artwork! Just look at that arrow!**

[image]

Comment: "A possibly better place would be a "statistics" page/tab to include all of that information." **YES**, this.

Comment: Hand-drawn circles are better!

Comment: Maybe such a stats page would be a good candidate for a new privilege: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253668/help-us-identify-micro-privileges-for-top-users We do already have a "Stats" page per queue; maybe somehow tossing the info into that part of the interface would make sense instead. http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats

Comment: @Frank that would make sense since you only get those queues at certain levels. The stats for individual queues I'm aware of but the OP was looking for a "cleaner" way to get to them. That's why I think a simple tab on the profile page would be a good place to see all of that quickly and compare/analyze your work in the different ques.

Comment: Sure, add it to the profile somewhere, but not as a third top-level tab. It's user activity, albeit summarized; keep it under the Activity tab. (But **fix the stats first**, they're so inconsistent as to be pretty useless at the moment.)